# I cannot subset my data frame using column values

Tags: r

I want to subset my data frame based on some specific values of a a column. my code is like :

```
data <- read.csv("file.csv")
data1 <- data[ ,wEEK_NO < 2]
 write.csv(data1, "joda.csv",row.names=FALSE)
```

but R gives me this error :

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , wEEK_NO < 2) : object 'wEEK_NO' not found
```

the column already exists,but I don't know why I receive this error. 
I would be thankful if someone can help.

Comment: wEEK_NO or WEEK_NO? `R` is case -sensitive.

Comment: `data1 <- data[ data$wEEK_NO < 2, ]`

Comment: As @user20650 states if you want to subset by row you need to put the condition to the left of the comma on the rows side.   `data[ data$wEEK_NO < 2, ]`  However as @user227710 notes the error message suggests that R can't find a variable named wEEK_NO.

Comment: @ user20650 @user227710 @ C8H10N4O2 thanks all, It was a mistake. but it's still giving me the same error. I also corrected the typo "wEEK_NO" into "WEEK_NO" but the error remains

Comment: Ghazal, can you post the error you get when you run `data[ data$wEEK_NO < 2, ]` please ... it can t be the same error

Comment: @ user20650 this is the error I received : Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , WEEK_NO < 2) : object 'WEEK_NO' not found        but it doesn't appear all the time!! today I ran exactly the same code without any error while  it kept giving me the error for whole night. I'm new to R, is it a normal thing to happen?

Comment: well you are getting that error as you are forgetting to add the dataframe details - see answer. You need `data[ data$WEEK_NO < 2, ]` not `data[ WEEK_NO < 2, ]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were three errors in your code, as follows

Use mtcars dataset as an example; to subset the dataset with the condition `disp < 200`

```
data(mtcars)
```

First your index position was wrong as C8H10N4O2 noted in the comments).
When subsetting a column you are wanting to select the rows that match your constraint.
You do this by adding the constraint in the row position `data[row, col]`

```
mtcars[mtcars$disp < 200, ]
```

You also need to tell R where `disp` is. So this will will give an error as there is no object called `disp` in the global environment. This seems to be the presistent mistake you are making.

```
mtcars[disp < 200, ]
```

> Error in `[.data.frame`(mtcars, disp < 200, ) : object 'disp' not found

So you also need to pass the dataframe name in the constraint `mtcars$disp < 200`

As user227710 noted in the comment, R is case-sensitive, so if an incorrectly spelled variable is passed, it will not be found as no rows will be returned

```
mtcars[mtcars$Disp < 200, ]
```

You misspelled your column name. I guess it should be `WEEK_NO`, with a capital 'W' and a capital 'O' instead of a zero.

If the error remains, check out `names(data)` to see what is the correct spelling.